# iOS Animation: how to implement split transition effect when one row of table view is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

Normally when one row is tapped, the detail view appears with a default animation. What I want is: When I tap one row of a table view, the row split from its middle,  the upper half fade in up from the middle of the row, and the lower half fade in down from the middle of the row, then the detail view appears.

Comment: Can you post code  that you have tried ?

Comment: You will have to use custom viewController transitions for this effect. http://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/custom-container-view-controller-transitions/